# Getting script error while connecting to Azure Devops through Visual Studio

Tags: azure-devops

Connection to Azure devops with Visual studio was working smoothly but after change of domain (Active Directory) password, it prompts for re-enter the credentials and after selection of domain email address it popups the following error:

[image]

Can anyone helps about how to resolve it?

Comment: Would also like to know if/how you solved this, I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Could you please clean the user data cache of Visual Studio?
You can delete the folder C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_xxxx to clean up the VS local cache

if issue persists, you could also try to clean the credential manager.
[credential manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNmVj.png)

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me.

1. Navigated to the azure git repo in the web browser. For example: https://dev.azure.com/myOrg/_git/MyProduct/
2. Got redirect to a *terms of use* page:
   https://myaccount.microsoft.com/termsofuse/consent?injectRequestBody
3. Accept the terms on that page.